# Remove records what is not contain in second table

Tags: mysql

I have to 2 tables:

lang_temp (newest data):

```
sku|postid|fi|en|ru (15000 records )
```

full_products:

```
sku|postid|fi|en|ru|xx|zzz|aaaa|bbb (15200 records)
```

postid are unique and it cant be same.

I need to delete full_products records by postid that does not exist in lang_temp table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM
  full_products
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM lang_temp l WHERE full_products.postid = l.postid)
```